# How to Change Scheduler Task User Password

Tags: windows, windows-7, wmi, wmi-query, wmic

When I Create Scheduler Task with the Username and Password in Windows 7 using Task Scheduler GUI and trying to Change the Password of User using Following Command line, it give me error in CMD

```
SCHTASKS /Change /RP test /TN "rtest1"
```

> Error:
>
> The Parameter is incorrect

Comment: That `rtest1` task must have been set using a different user name whose password is not `test`. Specify `/RU` also to make sure both user name and password matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PowerShell script to update scheduled task credentials](http://windowsitpro.com/scripting/updating-scheduled-tasks-credentials), which Bill Steward has written for this purpose (thanks a lot to him). This works also for tasks, which were created with the Windows task scheduler GUI and not from command line (or reimported or such). The webpage has all the explanations and example usage.

Note that you may need to run `set-executionpolicy unrestricted` in the powershell shell first to allow execution of the script.

Answer (score 4):

I Found the Following Solution for my Question, I want to Share it with you all.

I created a scheduled task like suggested above

```
schtasks.exe /create /S remotemgmt  /tn "Mytask" /tr "mspaint" /u admuser /p PassWord /sc "Monthly"/st "13:00" /F
```

Then I created  MyTask2 from the GUI, mirroring all the settings of the task created by schtasks

If I do:

```
schtasks.exe /change /S remotemgmt  /tn "Mytask"  /Ru domain\UberUser /Rp PassWord
```

That works as expected

If I try to run the same on MyTask2 it fails with the above mentioned error

```
schtasks.exe /change /S remotemgmt  /tn "Mytask2"  /Ru domain\UberUser /Rp PassWord
```

One thing I noticed is that if I export the XML files,  from MyTask and MyTask2 is that they are different, even though all the settings you can see in the GUI are the same.

The problem seems to be in the  tag:

If I created a task from the commandline and export it it looks like this: 2010-12-06T13:00:00

If I create/export it from the GUI i looks like this: 2010-12-06T22:13:59.9965698

If I open the exported XML file, and deletes .9965698 save the file,  Re Import it into Scheduled tasks

```
"schtasks.exe /change /S remotemgmt  /tn "Mytask2"  /Ru domain\UberUser /Rp PassWord" works
```

There are other differences in the XML files as well, it seems that when you create tasks using schtasks some  timespans are written in Hours, whereas if I create it in the GUI it is in days.

GUI : P3D

CLI: PT72H

These two are not set, when using the GUI to create the task:

PT10M
PT1H

These do however not affect the ability to change the settings afterwards with schtasks.exe.

Comment: Scheduled tasks created in GUI on Windows Server 2008 and Server 2008 R2 cannot be changed by schtasks.exe unless remove dot and 7 decimals in StartBoundary tag (Mentioned in http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2011/11/22/managing-scheduled-tasks-in-your-environment-part-ii/)

Answer (score 4):

For future troubleshooting, after the below steps failed me, I tried some additional tweaking and found that for me, I was unable to get my schtasks password change to work until I imported the XML less the Repetition portion of the XML, (i.e. the PT10M interval and the P1D duration). After I imported the XML without those pieces, I was able to go into the GUI and make those changes there. Afterwards, Schtasks worked for me to change the password.  Bizarre behavior!!

Comment: Same for me. Adding <Repetition> causes The parameter is incorrect.